# trying to create a list of deserialized data windows phone

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-phone-8, deserialization

I am currently trying to create a list of custom objects using data I get back from isolatedstorage, and deserializing it.

it worked perfectly yesterday and just keeps givin me this exception today, and I am not sure what to do?

```
{System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
at LandbouWP.ViewModel.StoryVM.GetStories(List`1 news_items)}
```

the code for getting the data and deserializing it:

```
            var loaded_result = settings["mainlist"].ToString();

            var s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>(loaded_result);
```

the deserializing works perfectly, so I don't think the issue is here, however does it maybe add another property or something to the list?

then I create a custom list of the returned items

```
   App.StoryViewModel.GetStories(s);
```

and that code is:

```
  public void GetStories(List<Object> news_items)
    {
        List<Story> a = new List<Story>();
        List<Story> b = new List<Story>();

        //loop over all items and add them for a viewmodel
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in news_items)
        {
            if (item.IsDeleted == true)
            {
                //do not add the item
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    a.Add(new Story
                    {
                        ID = news_items[i].ID,
                        IsDeleted = news_items[i].IsDeleted,
                        IsActive = news_items[i].IsActive,
                        Title = news_items[i].Title,
                        Author = news_items[i].Author,
                        Synopsis = news_items[i].Synopsis,
                        Body = news_items[i].Body,
                        ImageUrl = news_items[i].ImageUrl,
                        //CreationDate = DateTime.Parse(news_items[i].CreationDate),
                        CreationDate = news_items[i].CreationDate.Substring(0, news_items[i].CreationDate.IndexOf('T')),
                        LastUpdateDate = news_items[i].LastUpdateDate.Substring(0, news_items[i].LastUpdateDate.IndexOf('T')),
                        DisplayUntilDate = news_items[i].DisplayUntilDate.Substring(0, news_items[i].DisplayUntilDate.IndexOf('T')),
                        TotalViews = news_items[i].TotalViews,
                        Gallery = news_items[i].Gallery
                    });
                    i++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string msg = ex.ToString();
                    string msg2 = msg;
                }

            }
        }

        //try here to remove duplicates?
        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            if (!b.Contains(item))
            {
                b.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                b.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        var new_list = b.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate).ToList();

        //save all the stories
        story = new_list;
```

I cannot even go through each item individually that I am trying to set, it just throws length cannot be less than zero, and I am not sure what its talking about, I do not have a parameter in my class named Length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check carefully this place

```
CreationDate = news_items[i].CreationDate.Substring(0, news_items[i].CreationDate.IndexOf('T')),
LastUpdateDate = news_items[i].LastUpdateDate.Substring(0, news_items[i].LastUpdateDate.IndexOf('T')),
DisplayUntilDate = news_items[i].DisplayUntilDate.Substring(0, news_items[i].DisplayUntilDate.IndexOf('T')),
```

I suppose one of your dates just in wrong format and has no "T"

Comment: thanx alot! this was the issue